how to have free fix ip?
I have a Linux sftp server on my private 192.168.1.0/24 network.
I can reach this from the outside internet world via duckdns + port forwarding on the ISP's device.
This works great, but when the ISP gives me a new IP, there are various outages for given times, due to the IP change (DNS isn't updating real time, although the duckdns is already updated, so DNS TTL/cache issue).
Of course I can buy a fix IP VPS somewhere and put my sftp servers port to the remote vps port with eg.: ssh -R localIP:localPort:remoteIP:remotePort but that would cost money..
Question: is there a software or a service with which i can use a fix IP with my sftp server?

If that server is hosted within a home network, only your ISP can provide a fixed IP (normally, for a cost, if at all possible). No program will help you here. Dynamic DNS services do what you want, but as you mention, when the IP changes there could be small outages to refresh the DNS entry. You could try other similar services to see if they suit you better, but not much beyond that.

I'd recommend using a Tailscale VPN for this.  Since your goal seems to be connecting to your server from outside.  Tailscale will allow you to connect all of your devices.
For example, let's say your host running sshd at home is called home
Providing you can login to Tailscale on the remote machine, you can:
ssh username@home

With no need to forward ports, or any of your home network open to the internet.

The alternative is to have your machine ping the ip address to you via email or some other messaging channel, if duckdns or any other dynamic dns isn't TTL'ing fast enough.

I had done the dyndns route for many years and using a Tailscale network has made it so much easier.
https://tailscale.com
